# How make url to specific pill bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

i'm using bootstrap 5.1 and i've got pills tab like:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-start">
  <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills me-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-messages-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-messages" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-settings-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-settings" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-messages-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-settings-tab">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i make url to show content of ex. "pills-profile"? if I enter the address for pills in my browser, it will redirect and display it.

Comment: Does appending #pills-profile to the url work, if you enter it straight into browser?

Comment: @Spankied No it doesn't brother www.example.com/index.php#pills-profile not working.

Comment: Try  www.example.com/index.php/#pills-profile

Comment: That only works for divs which are always visible. For pills navigations, you'd need some sort of JS to detect the id from the URL and then make corresponding pill active.

Comment: @Spankied same, not wroking

Comment: Note @SiddharthBhansali comment, and check if pill-profile is even visible when user initially visits page.